# Determine the character of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{i\theta n}}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Determine the character of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{i\theta n}}{n}}$$

where $\theta$ is a real parameter.

I try to divide the series with De Moivre' s formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{i\theta n}}{n}}=\sum{\frac{cos(n\theta)}{n}}+i\sum{\frac{sin(n\theta)}{n}}$$

The initial series converges if both these series converge. In particular I have seen that for ${\theta}= \pi+2k\pi$ the series converge and for ${\theta}=2k\pi$ the series diverge.

Comment: You can solve this by using Abel summation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can divide the study of this series into three cases:
1) θ=0+2kπ, k is an integer
2) θ=2kπ
3) the other cases

then,
1) the series is the harmonic series which does not converge.
2) the series is $$∑(-)^n/n$$ that converges for Leibniz's Rule
3) For the Dirichlet's test the series converges.

In particular in the third point:

$1/n$  is decreasing, strictly positive and approaches to zero at the growth of n.
whit a sum from 1 to A, where A is a positive integer.

$$|∑_1^Ae^{inθ}|$$ $$≤$$ $$∑_1^A|e^{inθ}|$$ $$≤A$$  i.e. it's bounded.

In fact $$|e^{inθ}|$$$$=$$$$1$$ for the rule of the complex field.
So the series for θ≠kπ satisfies the hypothesis of the Dirichlet's Test and then converges.

Comment: consider latexing your answers for ease of reading, heres a brief tutorial : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 7):

Hint: consider the series

$$-\log{(1-z)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something basic here yet I can't see how this helps: the above series converges for $\,|z|<1\,\,\wedge\,\,z=-1\;$ , whereas $\,|e^{i\theta n}|=1\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: $z=1$ is a branch point, not a pole.  The series converges for $z=e^{i \theta}$ for $\theta \ne 2 \pi k$, $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For $z\not=1$, this series converges (by "partial summation", generalizing the alternating-decreasing criterion), although it certainly does not converge absolutely. This not-absolute convergence is easy to verify, without worrying about whether it still converges to $-\log(1-z)$, etc.

Comment: @RonGordon, I didn't say, nor implied, $\,z=1\,$ is a pole: it's easy to see it isn't. Yet, your hint still doesn't show the convergency you talk about or, at least, I can't see how. Now Paul Garret's hint is enough, together with Olivier's comment above.

Comment: @DonAntonio: not going to get into a senseless argument here.  The hint is what it is, and is correct.  I never claimed it to be a full and complete result.  My comment about branch points was an observation about why convergence is plausible, not an attempt to put words in your mouth.  I agree that Paul Garrett filled in the gaps.

Comment: I can not immediately use $-\log{(1-z)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ because we have not yet studied. I'd like to know how to derive this formula, or only one way to tell if the series converges or diverges.

Comment: You may derive this formula by integrating the geometric series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$$